# Convert Oracle Regex to HIVE

Tags: regex, hive

I need to convert the regex below, that works fine in Oracle, to HIVE. The regex Pattern Removes all punctuation except ('-' and '&' apostrophe, and spaces).

```
    select
       REGEXP_REPLACE (          
        TRANSLATE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE( 'UNI''C...ER - BÉBI,,, DAS DE PORTUGAL, SGPS, S.A.', '[^[:alnum:] &-]', '' ),
                    'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëü', 'ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeu'
                 ),
                    ' {2,}', ' ') SSS

from dual;
```

The problem is with the outputs:

1. Oracle Output : "UNICER - BEBIDAS DE PORTUGAL SGPS SA"
2. HIVE Output : "UNIC...ER - BEBI,,, DAS DE PORTUGAL, SGPS, S.A." (keeps '.' and ',')

I think that the problem resides on [[:alnum:]] POSIX Character Class interpretation.

Many thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
'[^\\p{L}\\p{N} &-]'
```

This regex matches any single character that is not (`[^...]` is a negated character class)

- `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
- `\p{N}` - any Unicode digit
- - a space
- `&` - a `&` char
- `-` - a `-` char.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll test and give you a feed back.

Comment: @LEOPOLDO In Hive, make sure you double escape backslashes, and if you test the regex in any regex tester, use a single backslash, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zT3k8I/1).